# How do I create a form to handle multiple inserts for i18n in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I need to create a form in cakephp so that I can insert content in multiple language at the same time.

For example, if I want to use `eng` and `esp` the form will be like:

```
Insert english title _____________
Insert spanish title _____________
```

I'm using i18n for the translated fields but the documentation doesn't say much, can anyone give me some advice?

Also, how can I know how many languages I'm using? Do I have to count the directories in app/locale?

Answer (score 3):

I keep an array in bootstrap.php for all the languages the site is supposed to support.
As for inserting translations, if you pass something like:

```
$data = array('ModelName' => array(
  'field_name' => array(
    'eng' => 'This is my name',
    'deu' => 'Das ist mein name'
  )
));
```

it will properly insert those in the i18n table.